# why is nvm (for windows) not working and whenever it runs it gives an error message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

nvm (for windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

I have downloaded the nvm-setup and installed it, but whenever it runs it gives an error message.

I've tried to reinstall the nvm, reset the PATH environment variable and install version 1.1.6, and non of it seems to be working.

NVM_HOME points to my nvm file correctly and it's in the PATH.

```
C:\Users>nvm --version

Running version 1.1.7.

C:\Users>nvm list

12.3.1

C:\Users>nvm use 12.3.1

exit status 1: 'D:\Program' ���O�����Υ~���R�O�B�i���檺�{���Χ妸�ɡC
```

Comment: I see a string of unprintable characters above. Is that just me - is there an actual error message there? Can you translate it please?

Comment: Do you have a file or folder called "D:\Program"? I assume that's meant to be "Program Files" but something is breaking parsing the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happend when you install nvm in a directory that have spaces in the name, for example: `C:\Program Files`

Change the install directory for nvm and it solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had to install the node in another location without spaces in path

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs -> C:\nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cmd with administrator privileges